# Huge CoreData migration in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, core-data

I have a CoreData sqlite files  `*.sqlite *.sqlite-shm *.sqlite-wal` in a zip format from my previous application version. The file is almost few hundred MBs.

In recent version, I have done some changes in the database schema i-e adding few new fields etc.

In Importing, I am simply replacing the current database by old database and making the user to restart application, which is crude. It does work however it causes 2 issues

> 1- It takes a lot of time on splash screen hanging the application.
>
> 2- If the database is big enough, the hanging time passes the Timeout
>   of Application and closes the application automatically.

What is the better way of importing database into core data saved in Documents as zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First detect whether you are doing a migration.  If you are, then display a ViewController with a spinner that explains what you are you doing ("please wait while we optimize the app"). When the database migration is done, the load your regular viewController.

This exact issue is discussed in this lecture: [Core Data Potpourri (Paul Goracke, February 13, 2014)](https://vimeo.com/89370886) around 58:00.  While the lecture is a bit dated (it was made before NSPersistentContainer) it is still one of the best I have ever seen and it is worthwhile to watch the entire video.